# Insert Method of Table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I've written some code in insert method of RBOLoyaltyMSRCardTrans table, it is working fine when I add some row from AX client, but I want this code to run when a transaction is occur in POS and data is written in this table, in this case my code is not running.

Any idea ?

Comment: show your code! is POS code using DoInsert? is insert overridden and not calling super?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Insert` method of a table will not fire in any of the following cases:

- Records are inserted with `doInsert()` method (and not `insert()`)
- Records are massively inserted with the SQL sentence `insert_recordset` with `skipDataMethod(true)` mofifier.
- Records are inserted from a Form and the `insert()` method of the Form Datasource is overriden and deleted the `super()` call.

Comment: Actually `insert_recordset` does call `insert()` if provided, unless you call `skipDataMetod(true)`.

Comment: That's true. `Insert_recordset` changes the action to record-to-record level when there is an `insert` method on the table. I've updated my answer.